# Extra vs Extraneous

Tags: synonyms, abbreviations, comparisons

I always thought "extra" is nothing but an abbreviation for "extraneous". However a friend of mine pointed out that the two are listed differently in the dictionaries, and have slightly different meanings. Is this accurate? What are the origins of these terms?

Comment: Have you looked up **extra** and **extraneous** in a dictionary? What meanings did you find?

Comment: Please [show the results of your own research](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/how-much-research-is-needed). Hint: [etymonline.com](http://etymonline.com) is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term *extraneous* actually derives from *extra* (from  Latin **extraordinarius**).

The current meanings of extra are probably a short of **extraordinary** as suggested by www.etymonline.com

Extra:

> - *1650s as a stand-alone adjective;* also used as an adverb and noun in 17c. (see extra-); modern usages -- including sense of "minor performer in a play" (1777) and "special edition of a newspaper" (1793) -- **all probably are from shortenings of extraordinary, which was used extensively in 18c. as noun and adverb in places we would use extra today.**

Extra- :

> - *only recorded in classical Latin in extraordinarius, but much used in Medieval Latin and modern formations;* it represents Latin extra (adv.) "on the outside, without, except," the old fem. ablative singular of exterus "outward, outside," comparative of ex "out of".

Extraneous:

> - 1630s, from Latin extraneus "external, strange," **from extra "outside of"** (see extra-).